# SQL, ORACLE - trim right string (remove all parameters from URL)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I query a column with URLs. Those URLs are from different origins and have different formats. Some of them have parameters. I wish to query this column and right trim the URLs from the first parameter symbol.

Example URLs:

```
URLs
http://www.domain1.com/path/page?parameters1&parameters2
https://www.domain2.com/path/page?parameters1&parameters2/somemorestufftoscrape
domain3.com/path/page?parameters1&parameters2
http://www.domain4.com/path/page&parameters1?parameters2
https://www.domain5.com/path/noparametershere.html
domain6.com/path/page=?parameters1&parameters2
```

I'll want to trim everything right from either ?,&,= (a list of characters that represent parameters for my case).

Desired Output:

```
TrimmedURLs
http://www.domain1.com/path/page
https://www.domain2.com/path/page
domain3.com/path/page
http://www.domain4.com/path/page
https://www.domain5.com/path
domain6.com/path/page
```

I've tried to use [RTRIM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2076.htm) as follows:

```
select
   URLs
   rtrim(URLs, '?=&') as TrimmedURLs
from
   MyTable;
```

The query returns but URLs column is equal to TrimmedURLs (am I doing something wrong?).

I've tried to use [regexp_substr](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_substr.php) but in the cases where there are multiple parameter charterers it trims from the last one and not the first one (see first note in page).

1. What is the query for the desired result?
2. Why does RTRIM not work for me?

Server is Oracle 11g
URLs Type is `VARCHAR2(1024)`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`REGEXP_SUBSTR()` sounds like the thing to use here:

```
with sample_data as (select 'http://www.domain1.com/path/page?parameters1&parameters2' url from dual union all
                     select 'https://www.domain2.com/path/page?parameters1&parameters2/somemorestufftoscrape' url from dual union all
                     select 'domain3.com/path/page?parameters1&parameters2' url from dual union all
                     select 'http://www.domain4.com/path/page&parameters1?parameters2' url from dual union all
                     select 'https://www.domain5.com/path/noparametershere.html' url from dual union all
                     select 'domain6.com/path/page=?parameters1&parameters2' url from dual)
select url,
       regexp_substr(url, '[^?&=]+', 1, 1) main_url
from   sample_data;

URL                                                                             MAIN_URL                                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------
http://www.domain1.com/path/page?parameters1&parameters2                        http://www.domain1.com/path/page                            
https://www.domain2.com/path/page?parameters1&parameters2/somemorestufftoscrape https://www.domain2.com/path/page                           
domain3.com/path/page?parameters1&parameters2                                   domain3.com/path/page                                       
http://www.domain4.com/path/page&parameters1?parameters2                        http://www.domain4.com/path/page                            
https://www.domain5.com/path/noparametershere.html                              https://www.domain5.com/path/noparametershere.html          
domain6.com/path/page=?parameters1&parameters2                                  domain6.com/path/page
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. Do you know what was wrong with my rtrim() approach?

Comment: @Oren From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions160.htm): `RTRIM removes from the right end of char all of the characters that appear in set.` So, if you had a string like `abc?&??=`, your rtrim would return `abc`. However, if your string is like `abc?&??=z`, there are no ?, = or & characters at the right hand end of the string to remove (the last character being z). What you were after was the portion of the string right up until the first ?, = or & character, which means you're after a substring. Hopefully that makes it clearer for you?

Comment: @Gary_W It depends on which part of the OP's requirement you use - if you go from the "I want to trim everything to the right of the ?, = and & characters", then it works. If you go from the expected output, you're right, the results from my query don't match. However, I'm going from what the OP said, and assuming that their expected output for domain5 was a typo.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't like `regexp`, you can also use a combination of `substr` and `instr` fonctions:

```
with sample_data as (select 'http://www.domain1.com/path/page?parameters1&parameters2' url from dual union all
                 select 'https://www.domain2.com/path/page?parameters1&parameters2/somemorestufftoscrape' url from dual union all
                 select 'domain3.com/path/page?parameters1&parameters2' url from dual union all
                 select 'http://www.domain4.com/path/page&parameters1?parameters2' url from dual union all
                 select 'https://www.domain5.com/path/noparametershere.html' url from dual union all
                 select 'domain6.com/path/page=?parameters1&parameters2' url from dual)
select 
    url,
    substr(url, 0, instr(url,'?')-1) main_url
from 
    sample_data
```

Comment: this one is not working when URL has no params. additionally it was asked about 3 types of parameter: `&`, `=` and `?`

Comment: OK, I didn't pay attention to this point. Good that the first solution works.